# $G$ is open in $(A,d)$ iff $G = A \cap U$ for some set $U$ that is open in $(M,d)$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

I've been working through Real Analysis by Carothers and need some help understanding the proof of this Proposition.

In the forward direction ($G$ open in $A \implies G=A \cap U$), the proof goes like this:

Suppose $G$ is open in $(A,d)$.

Then $\forall x \in G, \exists \epsilon_{x}$ such that $B^{A}_{\epsilon_{x}}(x)=A \cap B^{M}_{\epsilon_{x}}(x) \subset G$.

Set $U = \cup \{B^{M}_{\epsilon_{x}}(x) : x \in G \}$.

Clearly $U$ is open and apparently $U$ satisfies $G = A \cap U$.

I can't seem to figure out how the equality comes about.

Comment: In general, this is the definition of the subspace topology (metric spaces are a special case of topological spaces).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since

$$A\cap U = \bigcup_{x\in G} (A\cap B_{\epsilon_x}^M(x)) = \bigcup_{x\in G} B_{\epsilon_x}^A(x)$$

and $B_{\epsilon_x}^A(x) \subset G$ for all $x \in G$, then $A\cap U \subset G$. On the other hand, given $x \in G$, $x \in A$ (since $G$ is a subset of $A$) and $x \in B_{\epsilon_x}^M(x)\subset U$, so $x \in A\cap U$. Therefore $G \subset A\cap U$. This proves $G = A\cap U$.

Comment: It says I have to wait a few more minutes before I can accept it